# Can't seem to find an XPath with a value that contains double quotes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-2.0

I've read through the forums and apparently almost nobody has issues to find XPaths with values with double quotes, most posts I found talked about finding Xpaths to elements with values that had both single quotes and double quotes, so I decided to ask this question, I apologize if this is already answered elsewhere.

Anyway, the element I wanted to find goes more or less like this:

```
<a class="product" title="REALIZE  "WHY  NO.T"" width="454" height="423" alt="" id="">
    </a>
```

I tried changing the XPath several times without success, using Selenium Webdriver

```
'//a[@title="REALIZE "WHY  NO.T""]' 

'//a[@title="REALIZE \"WHY  NO.T\""]'

"//a[@title="REALIZE \"WHY  NO.T\""]"
```

These are a few of the ones I tried, there are a few more but I didn't save all the ones I tried

I feel like it might be a matter of me missing something terribly basic, but I've been looking for the answer for hours without success

Comment: Just surround the " with "" to escape it. But why aren't you using the class.

Comment: There are several with the same class and the title is the only thing I can use to target the correct element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//*[@title='REALIZE "WHY NO.T"']
```

You have to wrap content with single quotes, the python code will be ( escaping the single quotes

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title=\'REALIZE "WHY NO.T"\']')
```

Comment: @ludex could you accept nthe answer by clicking bthe tick sign

Comment: I ended up surrounding it with single quotes and it worked, ended like this:       
            ("//a[@title='"+'REALIZE "WHY NO.T"'+"']")                                                                                                               I guess that when a value has double quotes in it, I have to replace the "s with 's               Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote it, I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: ;no issues :)  glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You say " the element I wanted to find goes more or less like this:"

*"More or less"*? What on earth does that mean? Is it more like this, or less like this? How can we help you if we don't know exactly what it's like?

And then you say:

```
<a class="product" title="REALIZE  "WHY  NO.T"" width="454" height="423" alt="" id="">
    </a>
```

But that's not well-formed XML. How is the parser supposed to work out where the `title` attribute ends? The XML parser should throw it out at that point.

OK, you're probably using an HTML parser rather than an XML parser, and HTML parsers try to make sense of any old garbage you throw at them. But I've no idea what an HTML parser will do with this input. HTML parsers are smart, but they're not smart enough to work out which of these quotes are part of the attribute value and which of them mark its beginning and end. It's probably turned it into something quite different from what you were expecting, and that's why your XPath expression doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I changed the letters in the title because I didn't want to post exactly what the original title said. I only changed what the title said, and kept the basic structure of the old one -- it had the spaces and quotes in it. Luckily I tried what the guy above answered and it worked perfectly.  Also I didn't make the website but regardless of how badly that is formed, it still seems to work

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend
right-clicking the intended element > click inspect element > look over element in console > copy xpath > paste it and analyze how it outputs.

From there I would then compare it to your current solution and maybe tweak a thing or two.